# MUI and Next.js 13 using MenuItem and NextLink controlling padding, height so the anchor is as wide/tall as the MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

The "HTML":

```js
<MenuItem>
  <NextLink className={currentRoute == "/" ? "link--is-active" : ""} href={"/"}>
    HOME
  </NextLink>
</MenuItem>
```

The embedded anchor is surrounded by MUI padding, when clicking the nav link outside the anchor you get the nice mui effect, but the url doesnt change. How do you set the NextLink to be the full-width and height of the MUI MenuItem?

[Image showing the padding i want on the NextLink not the MUI wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYEH6.jpg)

I tried setting the padding and lineHeight of the MUI element sx prop to 0 and 1 respectively, but had no effect on the vertical padding

Answer (score 0):

Reversed the nesting and all works properly:

```
        <NextLink
            className={currentRoute == '/' ? 'link--is-active' : ''}
            href={'/'}
        >
            <MenuItem>HOME</MenuItem>
        </NextLink>
```